# MSMQ Trigger on Windows 2003 not firing

Tags: msmq, triggers

I'm having a strange issue with an MSMQ trigger. This is what I've done.

- On Windows Server 2003 I've installed MSMQ
- I then installed MSMQ triggers
- I created a private queue called "TestQueue"
- I created the rule as follows:

  - Name: "TestRule"
  - Condition: "Message label contains '-'" (All my message labels contain '-')
  - Invoke standalone exe: "C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE"
- I then created a trigger as follows:

  - Name: "TestTrigger"
  - User queue: ".\Private$\TestQueue
  - Peeking and enabled set
  - Attached the "TestRule" rule

I then have a console application that puts a message on the "TestQueue" (I can see the message on the queue), However the trigger does not start NOTEPAD.exe (I've been monitoring task manager to make sure)

Does anyone know why the trigger would not be firing?

Comment: I have got a similar issue except I am developing on Windows 7 machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up getting a clean install of Windows 2003 and re-installed MSMQ and it now works.